# Word with different format should stay inline

Tags: html, css

I can't get a word to stay inline when I want to style it differently. How to solve?

```css
p.SixtyFive {
  font-size: 20vw;
  text-indent: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="Intro">This page has</p>
<p class="SixtyFive">all</p>
<p class="Intro"> you want.</p>
```

I've tried different [solutions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp).

Also, I've tried to solve it with browser tools by selecting the specific element. That's how I got the attributes/properties below the text-indent property.

Comment: If you just want to change the font size, use a `span` tag rather than a `p` tag. But what you really want is for it to `display: inline` rather than `display: block`

Comment: Block-level elements take up a whole layout block, meaning they won't display inline. By default, `p` tags use `display: block`, while `span` tags use `display: inline`. But, even from a semantic perspective, you want `span` anyway --- `p` means paragraph (and will be treated as such by e.g. screenreaders), and the one word that you're trying to highlight is definitely not a paragraph in and of itself

Comment: 1 addition: The span element should be used within the <p> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `span` tag (which is inline by default), don't end the `p` tag before the span (but only at the end) and delete the `display: block` and all other unnecessary stuff from your css class rule:

```css
span.SixtyFive {
  font-size: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<p class="Intro">This page has <span class="SixtyFive">all</span> you want.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add display:inline to all the paragraph elements

html:

```
<p class="intro">This page has</p>
<p class="SixtyFive">all</p>
<p class="intro"> you want.</p>
```

css:

```
p.SixtyFive {
    font-size: 20vw;
    text-indent: 0;
    display: inline;
}
p.intro{
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: This worked but it removed the indent I wanted on my paragraph. I've also learned that the paragraph tag <P> should be used for a paragraph and not a single word.

Answer (score 0):

As @Toastrackenigma correctly said, you should use a `span` tag;

```css
span.SixtyFive {
  font-size: 20vw;
  text-indent: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="Intro">This page has</span>
<span class="SixtyFive">all</span>
<span class="Intro"> you want.</span>
```

Comment: You can add it back by giving an ID to the first span tag and setting `text-indent` to whatever value you want

Comment: This is a good solution although I wanted to style just 1 word differently within a paragraph so then the <p> tag with a <span> element inside of it would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `display: inline`, you need to use it on the **parent**, i.e. the element that encloses what you want to inline.

```css
p {
  display: inline;
}

p.SixtyFive {
    font-size: 20vw;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin-block-start: 0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
    margin-inline-start: 0;
    margin-inline-end: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="Intro">
  This page has</p><p class="SixtyFive">all</p><p class="Intro"> you want.
</p>
```

Comment: This worked but it removed the indent I wanted on my paragraph. I've also learned that the paragraph tag <P> should be used for a paragraph and not a single word.